# About two equinumerous partitions of the same set.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal {A,B}$ be partitions of a set $X$ into $m$ subsets. Suppose that for any $k\leq m$ and any $A_1,\ldots,A_k \in\mathcal A$ there are at most $k$ elements of $\mathcal B$ contained in $\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i.$ Does it imply that for any $k\le m$ and any $A_1,\ldots,A_k\in\mathcal A$, there are at least $k$ elements of $\mathcal B$ whose intersection with $\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i$ is non-empty?

I'm thinking about a problem which a positive answer to the above would solve. And the above appears plausible to me.

Both the hypothesis and the conclusion say something about any $A_1,\ldots,A_k.$ My first thought was to take any $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ and getting the conclusion from the hypothesis restricted to those particular $A_i$. But this doesn't work, and I don't have any ideas.

Comment: When you say subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ in $\mathcal A$, do you mean *elements* $A_1, \dots, A_k$ *of* $\mathcal A$? And what do you mean by "contained in"?

Comment: @dfeuer To the first question: yes, exactly. By "is contained in" I mean $\subseteq$.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify these and the rest.

Comment: Does the condition hold for all $k\le m$ or just for a single $k$?

Comment: @dfeuer Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by the rest. For containment, this is the standard meaning as far as I know. I'll edit to clarify the first question. Please feel free to edit as you wish.

Comment: @Hagen Any $k$. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Bartek: I've edited your phrasing a bit so that it's clearer to me – please check it's still what you meant (and feel free to revert it if you think this way is worse anyway)

Comment: @Ben Thanks. I've made some further changes.

Comment: FYI, there is no "standard" meaning of "contains". It can refer either to $\in$ or $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $X$ is non-empty and $m>0$. The implication does, indeed hold. In the case $k=m$, this is obvious, since $\mathcal A,\mathcal B$ are both partitions of $X$ into $m$ subsets. Now, suppose $0<k<m$, and take any $k$ distinct elements $A_1,...,A_k$ of $\mathcal A$. Put $j=m-k$ and let $A_1',...,A_j'$ be the other elements of $\mathcal A$. By hypothesis, there are at most $j$ elements of $\mathcal B$ contained in $$\bigcup_{n=1}^jA_n'=X\smallsetminus\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^kA_n\right),$$ so there are at least $m-j=k$ elements of $\mathcal B$ whose intersection with  $$ \bigcup_{n=1}^kA_n$$ is non-empty.